# UITableViewCell doesn't display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem with my TableViewController. There is a custom cell, with a class, and various infos dynamically loaded. My TableViewController appears, but my cell doesn't display, but i can touch this, and my transition with infos are good.
Thanks for your answers.

**TableViewController.m**

```
@interface Chat() {
    NSMutableArray *messages;
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableMessages;

@end

@implementation Chat

NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ChatCell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [_tableMessages registerClass:[ChatCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMessages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_tableMessages addSubview:refreshControl];

    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self loadMessages];
}

- (void)loadMessages {

    if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil)
    {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_MESSAGES_CLASS_NAME];
        [query whereKey:PF_MESSAGES_USER equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [query includeKey:PF_MESSAGES_LASTUSER];
        [query orderByDescending:PF_MESSAGES_UPDATEDACTION];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
             if (error == nil) {
                 [messages removeAllObjects];
                 [messages addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                 [_tableMessages reloadData];
             } else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
             [refreshControl endRefreshing];
         }];
    }
}

- (void)actionCleanup {
    [messages removeAllObjects];
    [_tableMessages reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [messages count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ChatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell bindData:messages[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DeleteMessageItem(messages[indexPath.row]);
    [messages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_tableMessages deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    PFObject *message = messages[indexPath.row];
    ChatView *chatView = [[ChatView alloc] initWith:message[PF_MESSAGES_ROOMID]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**TableViewCell.m**

```
@interface ChatCell() {
    PFObject *message;
}

@end

@implementation ChatCell

- (void)bindData:(PFObject *)message_ {
    message = message_;

    _chatImg.layer.cornerRadius = _chatImg.frame.size.width/2;
    _chatImg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    PFUser *lastUser = message[PF_MESSAGES_LASTUSER];
    [_chatImg setFile:lastUser[PF_USER_PICTURE]];
    [_chatImg loadInBackground];

    _chatUsername.text = message[PF_MESSAGES_DESCRIPTION];
    _chatMessage.text = message[PF_MESSAGES_LASTMESSAGE];

    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:message.updatedAt];
    _chatDate.text = TimeElapsed(seconds);

}

@end
```

Comment: Check whether how many rows are dispalying.

Comment: check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `NSLog(@"%@",cell)` check its nil or not.

Comment: @kevinPy might be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26881504/3767017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you register the cell using `- registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

If you register it this way you have to construct the view programmatically or load the nib file in `ChatCell` code.

### To solve the problem, do either of these:

- Create a nib file containing the view for your table view cell and set the class to `ChatCell`. Then use `- registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` to register the nib.
- Construct the view programmatically eg. create a `UILabel` and add it as a subview of `ChatCell`.
- Make the prototype cell in the storyboard and set the cell identifier to `ChatCell`. Then remove the `- registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

Answer (score 0):

**Check You are given correct cell Identifier in storyboard. (case sensitive)** `" ChatCell"`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ChatCell";
    ChatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell bindData:messages[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the UI on background thread. Try this, in your "loadMessages" method.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI here
            if (error == nil) {
                [messages removeAllObjects];
                [messages addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                [_tableMessages reloadData];
            } else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
            [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });

    }];
```